# Does $L^1$ convergence preserve the regularity of this sequence of functions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, limits-and-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of $L^1(]0,1[)$ functions such that $f_n$ is non-decreasing, at least left-continuous, $f_n(0^+) <0$, $f_n(1^-) >0$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$. This sequence converges

$$f_n \rightarrow f$$

in $L^1$. Is it true that $f$ is non-decreasing and at least left-continuous with $f(0^+) <0$, $f(1^-) >0$ ?

Comment: $f$ is only defined up to null sets, so you have to change the question to something like "does there exist a version of $f$ such that...".  However, you can prove everything that's true pretty quickly, using the fact that a subsequence converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: You might like to think about a sequence like $f_n(x) = -\frac{1}{2} + x^n$.

Comment: You will most definitely not be able to retain the **strict** inequalities that you require for $f(0^+)$ and $f(1^-)$; the best you can hope for are non-strict inequalities for the limit.